# Android PopupWindow Animation not working

Tags: android, android-animation, android-popupwindow

I am showing PopupWindow on button click from top-left corner of the screen. But the problem is, when I am opening it, it will shown very fast, that means no animation occurs, but when I am closing it, its working fine, that means it is disappearing with animation.

Here is my code, please help me.

**Main Class Code**:

```
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.eosos_maptype_popup, null);
            final TextView txtContacts = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.txtContacts);
            final TextView txtFeatured = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.txtFeatured);
           final PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(CalendarView.this);

            popup.setAnimationStyle(R.style.animation);


            popup.setContentView(layout);
            popup.setHeight(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            popup.setWidth(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            popup.setFocusable(true);
            popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources()));

            // popup.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP, rect.left -
            // v.getWidth(), getDeviceHeight() - rect.top);
            popup.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT, rect.left, rect.bottom);
```

**My style.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <style name="animation" parent="android:Animation">
        <item name="@android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/popup_show</item>
        <item name="@android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/popup_hide</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**My popup_show.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <translate android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0" android:duration="1000"/>
</set>
```

**My popup_hide.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="-100%" android:duration="1000"/>
android:duration="200"/> -->
</set>
```

Comment: Did you figure out what the problem was yet?

Comment: Ya I have solved this. @DaveNOTDavid

Answer (score 3):

I was having this tag in my main Activity Theme.

```
<item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
```

As soon as I removed it - "in" animation for PopupWindow started to work smooth.